# How do I deallocate the memory create in this function?

Tags: c++, opencv, xlib

I've done a lot of searching on google, and I'm still not sure about this.

```
cv::Mat ImageFromDisplay(int Width, int Height, int x, int y)
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    XWindowAttributes attributes = {0};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &attributes);
    XImage* img = XGetImage(display, root, x, y, Width, Height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
    if (!img->data) {
        cout << "No image data";
        throw("No image data");
    }
    cv::Mat scene = cv::Mat(Height, Width, img->bits_per_pixel > 24 ? CV_8UC4 : CV_8UC3, img->data);
    if (!scene.data) {
        cout << "Error reading scene";
        throw("Error reading scene");
    }
    cvtColor(scene, scene, CV_BGRA2BGR);
    XFree(img);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return scene;
}
```

Whenever I use this function, I later use cv::Mat->release on the object that is returned, like so:

```
cv::Mat sceneImg = ImageFromDisplay(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);
sceneImg.release();
```

Will all the memory allocated by this function be cleaned up once sceneImg goes out of scope?

I know that I call free on the img within ImageFromDisplay, and I call XCloseDisplay on display from ImageFromDisplay, so I'm assuming the memory for those data structures gets cleaned up. Do I need to delete sceneImg.data after sceneImg.release has been called?

Comment: no idea about the X stuff but for the openCV mat: you dont even need to release. once it goes out of scope and wasnt referenced by another variable its .data memory will be released automatically. openCV mat data uses reference counting!

Comment: I noticed that you're returning `cv::Mat scene` by value. Would't it be better to allocate memory once (outside of the function) and then return it by pointer?

Comment: That's a good point. I'm an amateur C++ programmer, so thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Found a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985586/65863) in the same place where I found the original code, pointing out the memory leak. Totally fixed my program.

> ... I wanted to say that the answer provided by Brandon leaks memory. **Use XDestroyImage(img); instead of XFree(img); in the function ImageFromDisplay**